# While creating realm object by json app crashing if type is mismatch in json object

Tags: ios, swift, crash, realm

While creating object by Json App, is crashing due to type mismatch.
How can i fix this crash using exception handling

```
class TestModel: Object {
    
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
}

let dict1: [String: Any] = ["id": 101, "name": "Sam"] //correct type

let realmObject1 = TestModel(value: dict1) //working fine

let dict2: [String: Any] = ["id": "101", "name": "Sam"] //wrong type in id

let realmObject2 = TestModel(value: dict2) //crashing
```

How can handle this crash

Comment: You should make id and name optional so that id the parameter even mismatch you wont have crash and also you should check the value type before setting to data like id value should be int.

Comment: thank you for your reply. is there any alternate option ?

Comment: In TestModel you can create initializer with conditions to set correct value before initializing.

Comment: I would think adding a simple convenience init to handle situations where it's the wrong type would be best. Then you can supply a default value when needed.